# Distribution of bounded summation of i.i.d random variables

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

We have a set of positive random variables $\boldsymbol X=\{X_1, X_2,\ldots\}$, where $X_1, X_2,\ldots$, are independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.). The CDF $F(x)$ and PDF $f(x)$ for $X_i$ are known in advance.

Define $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$.

As we can see $\boldsymbol X$ can be viewed as inter-arrival times for a renewal process, and $S_n$ denotes each arrival epoch.

Next we define a variable $K$: $K=\inf\, \{n\mid S_n>T\}$ (or $K=\min\, \{n\mid S_n > T\}$), where  $T$ is a constant.

Then

1. what is the distribution of $K$?
2. what is the distribution of $S_K$?

I already know that the PDF for $S_n$, denoted by $f_n$, can be computed by $f_n=f^{*n}=f*f*\cdots *f$, the $n$-fold convolution power of $f(x)$. By Laplace Transform, we can convert the convolution to multiplication.

Comment: For the first one, I think $K \geq n \iff S_n \leq T$.

Comment: @Ilya Yes, I agree. Then what can we do with $S_n\leq T$?

Comment: As you said, you already know the PDF for $S_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\{K\geqslant n\} = \{S_n\leqslant T\}$, we compute
$$K = \sum_{n=0}^{K-1}\mathsf 1_{(0,T]}(S_n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1_{(0,T]}(S_n)=m(T), $$
that is, $K$ is the renewal function evaluated at time $T$. It follows that
$$\mathbb P(K=n) = \mathbb P(m(T)=n) = \mathbb P(\mathbb E[N(T)]=n)=F^{\star n}(T).$$

As for $S_K$, observe that
$$S_K = T + (S_K-T) = T+Y(T), $$
i.e. $S_K$ is the sum of $T$ and the residual life at time $T$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So it seems difficult to computing the distribution of $K$ because $n$-fold convolution is involved. For $S_k$, I guess it's $T+(S_K-T)$ instead of $T+(S_k-T)$. Actually $A_T$ is the residual life of the current renewal since time $T$, right? You mean that $A_T$ has the same distribution as the age of the current renewal at time $T$? And how to compute the distribution of $A_T$?

Comment: You are correct that it would be the residual life (and not the age). In general, the distribution of the residual life at time $T$ does not have a simple closed form and depends on the time $T$.

Comment: I see. Considering that the closed form is difficult to get, Is there any approximations of the distribution of the residual life?